# $\Bbb Z[x]/(p)\cong \Bbb F_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

How do I prove this?
$$\Bbb Z[x]/(p)\cong \Bbb F_p[x]$$

This implies that $(p)$ must be equal to $p\Bbb Z$ where $p$ is prime. Why is the only prime element that makes this true $p$ where $p$ is prime? Why is $p\Bbb Z$ generated by $(p)$?

---

I know that $\Bbb Z/ p\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb F_p$ when $p$ is prime. I don't see why $p\Bbb Z\cong (p)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is your definition of $(p)$?

Comment: @Arpit Ideal in $\Bbb Z[x]$ generated by an element $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism of rings $\phi: \mathbf{Z}[x] \to \mathbf{F}_{p}[x]$ given by $\phi(f(x))=f(x)$ mod $p$ (taking the residues mod $p$ of the coefficients). $\phi$ is clearly surjective. An element is in the kernel if and only if it gets mapped to the zero polynomial in $\mathbf{F}_{p}[x]$ hence if and only if all its coefficients are multiples of $p$, so the kernel is the ideal $(p)=p\mathbf{Z}[x]$. The rest follos from the first isomorphism theorem. (In this case, the ideal is $p\mathbf{Z}[x]$ and not $p \mathbf{Z}$)

Comment: It seems the *first* thing one should address is the misconception that $(p)$ in $\bf Z[X]$ means $p\bf Z$, when it means $p\bf Z[X]$. Then the OP might be able to construct an isomorphism alone.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense. $(p)$ generates via $pr,r\in \Bbb Z[x]$ and since addition of these polynomials definitely yields a polynomial with integer coefficients $(p)$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ should mean $p\Bbb Z[x]$. Why is everyone opting not to use blackboard bold?